# JS node chart from SQL Server not updated

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, chart.js

I begin a website to report some data I store in a SQL Server database.

I use jsnode to access the data from the database, then use this data to make a chart.js

Chart.js is working good, reading the data from SQL Server is also working fine (using npm `mssql`), the problem is that my query function does not wait the end of the query to return my data, then the chart is never updated, even if I get the data later on on the console.

Below is the export function

```
exports.getProdData = function()
{
    sql.close()
    sql.connect(config).then(() => {
return sql.query`select * from Production_Data where PartNO = ${'T46'}`
}).then(result => {
// result stuffs
        var Data = result.recordset[0].Value;
        return Data;
  }).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
  })
}
```

Before running this function, I already have my connection set, and I checked using `console.log` that I receive well my data. The problem once again is that the return is done before the update of data based on the database content.

Anyone knows how I should proceed on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it sounds like you're receiving a Promise, which is being resolved later. Here's an example that shows how to run code once the promise is resolved:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Then, you'll have to set the data in your chart's dataset, and run
chart.update();

Here's an example of how to set the chart data:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html